# Maximum capacity on re module? Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been using python for web scraping. Everything worked like a oiled gear until I used it to get the description of a product which is actually a laaaarge description.

So, it's not working at all... like if my regex was incorrect. Sadly I can not tell you which website I'm scraping in order to show you the real example, but I actually know that the regex is actually ok... it's something like this:

```
descriptionRegex = 'id="this_id">(.*)</div>\s*<div\ id="another_id"'

for found in re.findall(descriptionRegex, response) :
   print found
```

The deal is that (.*) is like 25000+ characters

There's a limit of characters to reach on a re.findall() finding? There's any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Please, give us an example we can test.

Comment: I would bet you have some nested divs that are breaking things .... why wouldnt you use something like beautiful soup for this kind of thing? this may be a case of when you have a hammer(re) everything looks like a nail ...

Comment: ok... here is it: http://alfaome.ga/lipsum.txt

Comment: "*I actually know that the regex is actually ok*" - Your regex is not okay, if you intended it to match the sample you posted. `.` doesn't match `\n`, so `(.*)` won't match anything.

Comment: I've thought . was "all", which expression can I use? ([.\n]*)?

Comment: "*In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.*" -- http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: So, you might use `[.\n]`, or you might use `(?s).`, or you might pass `re.DOTALL` into your search function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `re.DOTALL` in your call to `.findall()`.

If you run this program, it will behave as you request:

```
import re
response = '''id="this_id">
blah
</div> <div id="another_id"'''

descriptionRegex = r'id="this_id">(.*)</div>\s*<div\ id="another_id"'

for found in re.findall(descriptionRegex, response, re.DOTALL ) :
   print found
```